# CSS svg color transition error in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I have a menu in css whose icons are svg. When you mouse over the button, change the color of the icon via a CSS transition. Interestingly, not all the buttons work. It depends on the content of the href. Why?

This works:

```
<li class="navButton">
  <a id="home" href="home.php">
   <span class="icon">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     x="0px" y="0px" width="30px" height="30px" 
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" 
     xml:space="preserve">

      <path class="icon_path" fill="white" 
       d="M256,69.972L50,275.815h42.507v166.213h326.985V275.815H462L256,69.972z 
          M374.492,397.028h-73.767v-86.495 h-89.451v86.495h-73.768V251.99
          L256,133.587l118.492,118.402V397.028z"/>
    </svg>
   </span>
   <span class="text">Home</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<li class="navButton">
  <a id="projects" href="projects.php">
    <span class="icon">
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     x="0px" y="0px" width="30px" height="30px" 
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512"
     xml:space="preserve">

       <path class="icon_path" fill="white" 
        d="M436.631,207.445v163.681L279.232,462V298.319L436.631,207.445z 
           M256,258.08l180.201-104.04L256,50 L75.799,154.041L256,258.08z 
           M232.768,298.319L75.369,207.445v163.681L232.768,462V298.319z"/>
    </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="text">Projects</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

If I change the href content, eg projects2.php works. Too crazy..

Comment: We'd need to see it in action. We don't really have enough information. CSS would be useful as well as JSfiddle

Comment: If the color change is dependent on the content of the href then you may have a css selector overriding the color that is uses an attribute selector such as a[href='home.php'] {color:#white;}

Comment: Funny, it works fine in jsFiddle...  http://jsfiddle.net/BuiltByEdgar/8yYbm/

Comment: If it works in jsFiddle, you've probably got styles elsewhere overriding it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is that the styles are overwritten, the class is the same for all buttons. The only difference is the href content...

Comment: magical suggestion: get rid of the name space declarations and enable-backgrounds and see if it works...